# Calling a Javascript function with parameters from innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing html in Javascript using innerHTML, in one case, I'm appending a href tag like so :

```
txt.innerHTML += '<a href="" id="rssLinks" onclick="goToUrl(' + url + ');">Read more</a>';
```

where url is a string containing a url.

And the goToUrl function looks like as follows :

```
    function goToUrl(urlToBrowse) {
       window.open(urlToBrowse, "_blank");
    }
```

But my onclick never gets called, can anyone see the problem? Cheers

Comment: hint: `alert` your string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
txt.innerHTML += "<a href='' id='rssLinks' onclick='alert(\"" + url + "\");'>Read more</a>";
//........................................................^............^ 
//.............................................................may needed
```

because call would look like goToUrl(http://google.com)

and that's a string so it has to be goToUrl("http://google.com")

**EDIT 01/2020 - "New" way to add this parameter**

Since ES6, you can write it with a Template-String

```
txt.innerHTML += `<a href='' id='rssLinks' onclick='goToUrl("${url}");'>Read more</a>`
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying this, but I have a problem, I alerted my string before quotes, and it looks like as follows :

goToUrl(http://www.test.com/content......);

and then after I tried to add the surrounding strings as you showed, it looks like this : 

goToUrl("http:="" www.test.com="" content="" ....);

Comment: I tried with turned quotes but the url still becomes malformed

Comment: now... :D try and error but this should work now! ^^

Comment: Hi, just one more small problem - it looks fine in the alert, but now there are html "&quot" surrounding the link and my function doesn't get called

Comment: guess you have a function like php htmlentities ? may innerHTML forms it like this...

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
onclick="goToUrl(' + url + '); return false;"
```

That will prevent the action of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append onclick to your element `txt.onclick="goToUrl(' + url + ');`